# AdaptiveCards extensibility

Tags: javascript, adaptive-cards

We need to override the default render for "Action.Submit" element (we just need to remove "aria-label" attribute from HTML that is generated by default).

But regarding this documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/adaptive-cards/sdk/rendering-cards/javascript/extensibility it is required using TypeScript.
Also, the above documentation provides only creating the new element, but not extending the existing element.

Please, could anyone provide the example how to override default render for any standard AdaptiveCard element with using plain JS?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Were you able to find a solution?